# how can I convert multiple rows into one row

Tags: sql-server, query

Imagine I have a table like this:

```
---------------------------------------------
Name | Property_1 | Property_2 | Property_3  |
---------------------------------------------
jimi | tall       | null       | null        |
---------------------------------------------
jimi | null       | black      | null        |
---------------------------------------------
jimi | null       | null       |  African    |
----------------------------------------------
```

I want to convert that to this table:

```
------------------------------------------------
Name | Property_1  |  property_2   | Property_3 |
------------------------------------------------
jimi | tall        | black         |African     |
-------------------------------------------------
```

how can I achieve that in MSSQL database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

while other values of a column are `NULL`, easily you can use this query:

```
SELECT Name,MAX(property_1),MAX(property_2),MAX(property_3)
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY Name
```

Comment: @el.ham, you forgot to add `Name` in the `SELECT` list.

Comment: @Bijujose Yess thaanks